# VBA: manipulating 2 dimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Im new to VBA and i have a question about 2-dimensional arrays. I have a 2d array with data like so:

```
Dim MyArray(10, 10) As String ' array definition should be 10, 10 as you 10 by 10 elements

MyArray(1, 0) = A
MyArray(2, 0) = A
MyArray(3, 0) = A
MyArray(4, 0) = J
MyArray(5, 0) = J
MyArray(6, 0) = J
MyArray(7, 0) = A
MyArray(8, 0) = T
MyArray(9, 0) = T
MyArray(10, 0) = J

MyArray(0, 1) = b
MyArray(0, 2) = b
MyArray(0, 3) = g
MyArray(0, 4) = k
MyArray(0, 5) = k
MyArray(0, 6) = b
MyArray(0, 7) = g
MyArray(0, 8) = u
MyArray(0, 9) = u
MyArray(0, 10) = u
```

So the data will look like this:

```
[A, b]
[A, b]
[A, g]
[J, k]
[J, k]
[J, b]
[A, g]
[T, u]
[T, u]
[J, u]
```

With this data, i want to traverse down the 2nd column and if the preceding character and the current character are identical, then remove its corresponding character in the first column.
Here is what i want the array to look like:

```
[A, b]
["", b]
[A, g]
[J, k]
["", k]
[J, b]
[A, g]
[T, u]
["", u]
["", u]
```

Can anyone give me a pointer in the right direction for a loop algorithm that will achieve this?

Comment: how last j becomes empty its preceding character is T

Comment: Arrays doesn't work like that, the second index cannot exceed 2! Also index starts at zero, so you are leaving out the very first one.

Comment: Like @PatricK said but you need to decide whether you are going to work with zero-based indexes (e.g. 0 to 9) or one-based indexes (e.g. 1 to 10).

Comment: @raghavendra - I believe the comparison is on the second rank but the value in the first rank is to be removed.

Comment: yes understood. try the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below code to display your 10 by 2 data, once you understand the loop, you can work on your checking, have fun!

```
Option Explicit

Sub ArraysExample()
    'Dim MyArray(10, 2) As String ' This is actually 11 rows by 3 coulms
    Dim MyArray(9, 1) As String ' This is what you should have for 10 by 2
    Dim rMax As Long, cMax As Long ' Max of Rows and Columns
    Dim r As Long, c As Long ' Rows and Columns
    Dim sTmp As String ' Temporary text

    MyArray(0, 0) = "A"
    MyArray(1, 0) = "A"
    MyArray(2, 0) = "A"
    MyArray(3, 0) = "J"
    MyArray(4, 0) = "J"
    MyArray(5, 0) = "J"
    MyArray(6, 0) = "A"
    MyArray(7, 0) = "T"
    MyArray(8, 0) = "T"
    MyArray(9, 0) = "J"

    MyArray(0, 1) = "b"
    MyArray(1, 1) = "b"
    MyArray(2, 1) = "g"
    MyArray(3, 1) = "k"
    MyArray(4, 1) = "k"
    MyArray(5, 1) = "b"
    MyArray(6, 1) = "g"
    MyArray(7, 1) = "u"
    MyArray(8, 1) = "u"
    MyArray(9, 1) = "u"

    rMax = UBound(MyArray)
    cMax = UBound(Application.Transpose(MyArray)) - 1 ' Transposed are 1 based, so you need to subtract 1

    ' To Display data visually
    For r = 0 To rMax
        sTmp = "["
        For c = 0 To cMax
            sTmp = sTmp & MyArray(r, c)
            If c = cMax Then
                sTmp = sTmp & "]"
            Else
                sTmp = sTmp & ", "
            End If
        Next
        Debug.Print sTmp
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I've never used `.Transpose` to pick up the UBound of the second rank. Nice trick!

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks, I found that out previously from [other sites](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/629320-application-transpose-visual-basic-applications-array.html), but cannot find MSDN reference. I have no tricks if the array is more than 2D...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
For i =1 to 9 'exclude first element
    if MyArray(0, i) = MyArray(0, i-1) then
        MyArray(i, 0) = ""
    end if
debug.print i & ', 0: is ' & MyArray(i, 0)
next
```

Answer (score 1):

See if the results sent to the VBE's Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) through the Debug.Print statements will help you make sense of it all.

```
Sub arrTest()
    Dim vARRs As Variant, v As Long, w As Long

    ReDim vARRs(0 To 9, 0 To 1)
    Debug.Print LBound(vARRs, 1) & ":" & UBound(vARRs, 1)
    Debug.Print LBound(vARRs, 2) & ":" & UBound(vARRs, 2)
    Debug.Print "---"

    vARRs(0, 0) = Chr(65)
    vARRs(1, 0) = Chr(65)
    vARRs(2, 0) = Chr(65)
    vARRs(3, 0) = Chr(74)
    vARRs(4, 0) = Chr(74)
    vARRs(5, 0) = Chr(74)
    vARRs(6, 0) = Chr(65)
    vARRs(7, 0) = Chr(84)
    vARRs(8, 0) = Chr(84)
    vARRs(9, 0) = Chr(74)

    vARRs(0, 1) = Chr(98)
    vARRs(1, 1) = Chr(98)
    vARRs(2, 1) = Chr(103)
    vARRs(3, 1) = Chr(107)
    vARRs(4, 1) = Chr(107)
    vARRs(5, 1) = Chr(98)
    vARRs(6, 1) = Chr(103)
    vARRs(7, 1) = Chr(117)
    vARRs(8, 1) = Chr(117)
    vARRs(9, 1) = Chr(117)

    'show data before culling
    For v = LBound(vARRs, 1) To UBound(vARRs, 1)
        Debug.Print vARRs(v, 0) & " - " & vARRs(v, 1)
    Next v
    Debug.Print "---"

    For v = LBound(vARRs, 1) + 1 To UBound(vARRs, 1)
        If vARRs(v, 1) = vARRs(v - 1, 1) Then _
            vARRs(v, 0) = vbNullString
    Next v

    'show data after culling
    For v = LBound(vARRs, 1) To UBound(vARRs, 1)
        Debug.Print vARRs(v, 0) & " - " & vARRs(v, 1)
    Next v

End Sub
```

Results:

```
arrTest
0:9
0:1
---
A - b
A - b
A - g
J - k
J - k
J - b
A - g
T - u
T - u
J - u
---
A - b
 - b
A - g
J - k
 - k
J - b
A - g
T - u
 - u
 - u
```

As you can see, I prefer variant arrays but the methods are pretty much the same. Using the [LBound function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a7w1ac(v=vs.90).aspx) and [UBound function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx) helps keep track of the scope of the array in both ranks no matter whether you are using one-based or zero-based dimensions.